# Derivation of pressure in the kinetic theory of gases

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Pressure_and_kinetic_energy),

> The pressure exerted by the collisions of the N gas particles with the surface can then be found by adding the force contribution of every particle and dividing by the interior surface area of the volume
>
> [image: Blockquote]

I have doubt about the multiplication by $N$. It seems to suggest that those $N$ particles hit the wall of the container at the same time, which is utter nonsense to me because these particles move randomly in the container and it seems unlikely that they all collide with the wall at some instant. Do I miss any important facts? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't $\bar F$ the average force per particle?

Comment: think of it this way that it is talking about a small time interval. All particles hit the wall once in this time interval.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kinthe.html#:~:text=Gas%20Pressure%20from%20Kinetic%20Theory&text=The%20average%20force%20and%20pressure,the%20molecular%20motion%20is%20random.